# How to deal with an intern's lack of basic skills?

Tags: software-industry, management, communication, internship, team

Due to some internal reorganization, now my team includes a new intern. Since I'm the technical and team lead, it's up to me to bring the new guy up to speed with how we work and what we need to do make our software run smoothly.  He has been with us for 4 months, and his internship can last up to 24 months by current legal rules.

The intern showed some promise - he had a full year of a technical course in Software Development in one of the languages we use and had previous experience as a freelancer doing small software projects. The stuff he showed us was simple but looked good for someone who was just learning the business, so we got him aboard.

However, working with him for a few months made a few issues visible. He barely can write any software - even really simple examples from an exercise book we got him - and has some real difficulty remembering core concepts we deal with everyday, even the most basic ones.

I'm actively teaching him for at least two hours a day every single day for two months now, and while he is showing some advances, they are rather small. It's a very frustrating experience for me overall - I've had several other interns before, and none showed such slow-paced advances.

This is not the problem, however.

Today I was reviewing some code with him, explaining some business logic, and he asked me about what exactly was happening on a certain line of mathematical code - it gave a discount on some values multiplying it by a decimal value (0.95 in this case). It was a pretty simple line of code and he showed a huge surprise about "making a number smaller by multiplying it by something". At first I thought it was a little funny and went on giving a few examples how that works out using fractions to clear what I thought it was a silly remark, but as I went on with my examples it became more and more clear that his math knowledge was really restricted.

It made me absolutely frustrated. I lost my patience and dropped several harsh remarks, in special my disbelief that he managed to leave high school with such lack of knowledge. I got specially angry and gave up teaching him for the day, telling him that this sort of lack of skill was unacceptable in the software industry.

Now I'm stuck with a bit of guilt. Maybe I was too harsh on him, maybe I was wrong on getting so upset with his lack of skill. I'm failing to deal with my frustration with him and I have no idea how to deal with it with more patience.

How do I keep my calms while dealing with such under-skilled coworker when I have to *teach him*? Can I call his attention to his lacking skill set? Or, is it something I should just ask for HR do deal with and send him on his way for another job?

Comment: In Germany, when you do an apprenticeship that lasts three years to become a software developer (I'd say a lot more people do this than study CS or similar at uni), you need to attend vocational school for about one third of the time (you work the rest). Because that school counts towards the 12 years of mandatory schooling, there are German, English and Politics classes besides the obvious programming, engineering, marketing and economics ones. Math is not taught at all in that school.

Comment: Why the VTC? This question is about "Hard conversations", which I'm pretty sure is on-topic on the site.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation (35 comments) has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51187/discussion-on-question-by-thales-pereira-how-to-deal-with-an-interns-lack-of-ba).

Comment: Just to add to the many good responses here - you may want to find out where this person graduated high school, and make sure HR doesn't send you any others from there, assuming that's an option. The high school has clearly failed.

Comment: @DonBranson agreed - have a chat with HR and see if the hiring process can be improved with more technical testing.  Won't help here but could reduce the future likelihood of a bad hire.

Comment: x * 0.95? How about trouble multiplying two single digit whole numbers? Had that with one of my former colleagues. Good question. Basic Maths knowledge is becoming a problem these days.

Comment: Maybe you were the one having your people skills tested without knowing it.

Comment: It could be that his interests simply lie somewhere else, I used to work as a programmer and hated it, I can't do math (it's like dyslexia with numbers) so I know I will never be a good programmer.
Once I figured that out I started doing front end design instead, way less logic to program and I really excelled in this field.
Tldr: maybe talk to him and see what he really likes to do.

Comment: If you do not believe he has the necessary skills find someone else. Yelling at him isnt going to solve the problem.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, but in Germany, afaik, multiplication and fractions are grade-school material.

Comment: @mathreadler: Hah, nice! The cruellest employee assessment ever conjured, and it could have gone on for 24 months had the OP performed better at it! ;)

Comment: Cut him loose. It will be better for everyone.

Comment: Is this story even true?

Comment: @Joker While it might seem fantasy for some people, once you become a manager or a team lead you end up with several weird tales under your belt. Stroll around the site a bit more - I'm pretty sure a lot of situations presented here seem almost cartoonish, but they are unfortunately pretty real.

Comment: Unacceptable. You talk abou HIGH SCHOOL? Seriously? That is stuff people learn in basic school, not high school. And that is not "math" as in "demanding math" - as much as cooking spaghetti is not making you a cook. This is nonfunctional in a simple basic knowledge for everyday life.

Comment: @TomTom That's why I got so frustrated with him. I'll never expect someone who is doing college, and an IT course nevertheless, being unable to do simple fractions.

Comment: "Since I'm the technical and team lead, it's up to me to bring the new guy up to speed with how we work and what we need to do make our software run smoothly." It's up to you make sure he is brought up to speed, not up to you to do it. Maybe someone in your team would be a good coach/mentor.

Comment: I am so saddened by the number of folks who think that an internship is for the company's benefit. It's not. The purpose of an internship is for the student to "get their hands dirty" and learn in the real world. If there's any benefit for the company, it's getting your hooks into that *rare*, ***RARE*** kid who's just a genius. 99% of interns are a time suck. No one should expect these kids to make us more productive.

Comment: I'm not surprised at this at all to be honest. I did a HND in college and everyone in my class left with at least a pass in programming, but only about 2-3 of them could actually program anything without a tutorial to explain things to them despite having certificates saying 'yes this person can program'. I'm also not suprised the person didn't know the relationship between fractions and decimal numbers. Until I started doing programming I had no need for fractions, trigonometry etc, so I had to relearn them alongside programming.

Comment: The question is unanswerable without the following basic context: why is your company obligated to keep employing them? and are you obligated to keep them on your team? Based on what you said, their productivity is negative and your group would be better off without them. Why can't you either reassign/transfer them to something they can do/ another group, or fire them? it's not up to you to clean up HR's messes and bad interviewing. This is not about hard conversations with the intern. It's about you figuring out what to do with them if they will always be destroying you productivity.

Comment: @smci Interns on my country are a delicate matter. You can't simply juggle them around and do whatever you please with them. Internships are tied to educational entities (high-schools, universities, etc) and there are _a lot_ of laws regarding what we can and can't do with them. Legally, you're obligated to give to each intern a mentor and the intern can only do which tasks he was hired to do. You need to fill a report every six months to his institution regarding the intern's progress.

Comment: @smci Sure, a lot of people don't follow the laws regarding internship, but my employee likes to do things "by the rules" and we do everything the law mandates, every if is incredibly inconvenient and unproductive. And, we're not really obligated to employ them, but using interns leads to paying less taxes, and so it's interesting for the business.

Comment: But are you legally obligated to keep the same mentor for those 24 mths? i.e. it has to continue being you. And even if, I still don't see that you're obligated to teach them for two hours every day. If yes to all that, what do other people do when they get bad interns?

Comment: @smci I'm the only one on IT that gets interns here. Other departments don't have the deep needs that IT has regarding internship, so things like lacking math skills aren't really a problem.

Comment: Yelling was wrong and might have broken something beyond repair already.  In the case that the situation can be mended (an apology is probably helpful in this case and will in any case be good for your reputation) you need to consider whether the intern can be (made) useful in a decent amount of time.  Discuss the situation with him and with your fellow managers.  Consider what tasks you can offer.  Consider less his current (lack of) knowledge but most of all his learning speed.  From what you already wrote, this doesn't sound promising.

Comment: @T.Sar Do you have any updates about this story/problem? What happened in the end? Thanks.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I apologized to him, and them tried to find another job that he could do with less demanding maths. Since he is pretty good on photoshop and other drawing/design tools, I put him to help me designing icons, backgrounds, logos, etc for the systems, reports, and stuff like that. I'm still trying to teach him how to program effectively, but with far lower expectations now.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

First step is to apologize to the intern.

It's likely both of you are frustrated with how the time has been going. If the intern has had a year of college, it means they are basically a high school student still. Not a professional software developer.

You need to set your expectations more correct. Often (most?) internships aren't really value-add in themselves, but are more of a recruiting/fulltime interview tool. Two years is a long time, though, but keep in mind this intern has friends who you may actually want to hire - hearing that your company yelled at an intern is *not* good for your company (even if it makes this one leave).

In my last fulltime job, I was told that it would be about a year before my boss expected me to be fully up to speed. A year! There is probably a difference in scope and responsibility of work, but an intern just out of high school is *going* to take a while to become useful (if they ever do...).

I have written [at length](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7482/how-can-i-get-off-on-the-right-foot-with-a-new-intern/7491#7491) here about the intern/manager relationship. You might find that beneficial to read.

A couple key next steps.

1. **Figure out what self-learning tools you can use**. Managing an intern will be a lot of work, period, particularly at the beginning. Delegate this as best possible (to free resources, the Internet has TONS of them)

   - You might have to accept this intern will not be productive, period
2. **Talk with someone at your company** who understands the legal pieces here if your company chooses to try to fire the intern.

   - Understand what needs to be done. If you need X, Y, and Z to let the intern go on their review, you want to make **sure** you know that now, rather than 30 minutes before it.
3. **Try to find work which fits**. Maybe the intern isn't great at X or Y or even all the things you want them to do. Talk and try to figure out what they are good at.

   - If you've decided the intern is useless just ask them what they want to do. A motivated intern working on things they want to do *probably* is more beneficial than an unmotivated one working on things they can't do.
   - *Most* people will not enjoy feeling terrible at their job anyways, you might find the intern hates their job now
4. **Be a pull, not push, resource.** When you work with the intern, make them come to you with questions - give rough guidance, but don't try to teach everything.

   - Mentorship is about providing opportunities for another to learn. **NOT** information dumping
   - It's ok if the intern struggles for a few hours (or even a day or more) on a task. That's how we learn best.
   - Avoid answering questions without questions of your own. "How do I do X?" --> "what have you tried?" etc
5. **Figure out why he got hired and fix your interview process**. If you accidentally hired this intern, make sure you don't hire a similar one again (or at least, figure out a way to make it less likely).

And this situation pretty much is bad for everyone. You may find that the intern is even unhappy and would voluntarily leave if it's an option. If you open the conversation it may resolve itself entirely.

Comment: I think this is the best answer of them all. It's worth apologizing. The OP should remember this is an intern we're talking about, not a professional programmer. When this is all over, try to get a look at your hiring processes to prevent this from happening again. Also, try to keep your cool, it's key to being professional.

Comment: I'd expand "Self Learning tools" - figure out the shortfalls (basic math). Then add a review with bullets ( 3.b: Issues with Basic math). Then work together to create a plan to overcome those shortfalls (Intern means student? Math classes at his/her college? Company have accounts with online "schools"? Khan Accademy, [Alison Math Certificate](https://alison.com/learn/maths), [Math Planet](http://www.mathplanet.com/), YouTube, iTunes U, etc, etc, etc).

Comment: @WernerCD: that is not the function of an internship, and learning basic math is not something which can be done in a few months (there is a reason that math stays with you from first grade to the end of your high-school). Doing so would actually be worse to the guy because one of the important lessons which can be learned in internships is a comparison of your knowledge to your peers - these are the people which you will compete against later - if something significant is missing on your side, it's bad. Working "together" with him on basic math  may give him the impression that it is ok.

Comment: This answer is very good, thank you. I'm already taking a few of your suggested steps (your #4 is mostly how I roll), and I think you're correct about apologizing to him. This was the first time I was "gifted" with a intern with this skillset, so I'm still adapting to mentoring him.

Comment: @ThalesPereira keep in mind that if it takes the intern 2 hours to do what you could help him with in 15 minutes it _still_ probably is beneficial for you to have the intern spend the 2 hours (or even more potentially).

Comment: @Sascha Not the function of an internship? It's the function of professional development and a part of every job I've ever had. Job has requirements A, B, C, D. You get a review and ratings of some sort. You are expected to fix issues. Everyone has strengths and weaknesses. Why wouldn't a formal review process - with goals, resources and a formal process of correcting your issues - be a part of internship as well? Aren't you training them to be professionals? Isn't part of the process to help them help themselves?

Comment: It just blows my mind that "Well, you are deficient in this area... to bad" is upvoted. I hope I never have to work with in that kind of environment.

Comment: 5, assumes there is a problem with the interview process. There might not be, he may just not respond well to this form of teaching. Going back to the examples of the interview, that he showed and asking about how he got there might prove helpful. He either copied them or he was able to produce the code by..... And this is the bit you want and might help going forward

Comment: @Drifter104 if you fire someone who you hired thinking they were great, you should definitely look critically at your interview process. You can't be perfect but opportunities like this are the only chances you really get for that sort of improvement.

Comment: @WernerCD: The function of an internship is to learn a specific practical skillset in order to solve a real problem under supervision in a complex, realistic environment. It is *not ok* if somebody has a 6 month internship where he supposed to apply matlab/simulink every day, and in reality he learns first basic math, then calculus, and spends 80% of his time to understand an formulate the problem and 20% on matlab/simulink. (i have seen such internships, and the results were embarrassing for everybody).

Comment: @Sascha While I get that internship isn't supposed to be and end-all-be-all project where the company fixes everything about a candidate... I just can't believe that constructive feedback (This is where we feel you are deficient), a plan of remediation (These classes, these objectives, this certification, etc) and follow up (It's been a month since we asked you to fix problem X... lets see where you are)... I can't believe that a review is "outside" of what's expected in a professional environment just because "intern". Just my 2c and disbelief.

Comment: @WernerCD: You can review his performance with him. But if his problem is that he cuts corners whenever he doe not like something, then "helping" him is actually not helping him. You suggest ("Then work together to create a plan") to make a plan with him for something which will take longer than the internship. Before you start do that you would have to seriously test him. If you go this path, clear with your boss if investing so much time is ok for your employer - if not do it on private time outside the internship.

Comment: @Sascha `if he cuts corners` definitely. If he's not helping himself, then you shouldn't help him either. `takes longer than the internship` the OP has said they are months into a ~2 year internship. But even if it was an "over the summer" thing - I just think it'd be the professional thing to do to say "Hey, We may not be there on the other side, but this is what you need to work on." Some of these fixes (basic math) should be fixed on the interns private time - and that's okay to put in the review. But, just my opinion, it's the professional thing to do in communicating that to the intern.

Comment: I just wanted to add here that, learning code is literally a whole different language. And you can teach someone the syntax (or letters in a spoken language) over and over, but until they understand for themselves and it 'clicks' to them, they won't be able to form sentences (write unique code) with them. 

I know a lot of developers who create some awesome projects by using resources and examples they found and modifying it, because that helps them better than flat out writing something new. If he did small software work, that may have been what he was doing, prior to the internship.

Comment: "In my last fulltime job, I was told that it would be about a year before my boss expected me to be fully up to speed. " So was I, and a month later I was berated for not being fully up to speed yet...

Comment: @drifter You think that the hiring process for a *technical position* that ended up with someone who is incapable of doing basic math on the level of a 12 year old (I think I'm generous here) is not flawed? An interview process for a programming position that does not involve programming is demonstrably broken. That said it's not the fault of the intern that they got hired for a position they're not fit in, so it shouldn't be taken out on them - it's most certainly the most uncomfortable for them.

Comment: @voo no I think as per the OP, they were able to show they put together some code. Now they either cheated (copy paste) or they were able to understand enough on the concepts involved to write that code. If they were able to write that code they gained that knowledge somehow. Its the somehow that was the point of my comment. Not everyone learns in the same way, in this case it might be worth changing the teaching method to one that is better for the intern

Comment: The problem here is the programming test. I went through quite some of them last year, and they generally fall into one of the following categories: * Pathetic (what is a loop?) or * Extensive and comical in scope (Write an exchange market simulator. TImeframe: 4 hours. Full unit testing and production quality code please) or * Irrelevant low level (system level database structure references that you use when building a database engine) for a high level web backend job, where the answer is "I use a database", not "I write my own btree in memory". Not seen one that was relevant and not a shame.

Comment: Realistically, at least regarding the math thing, it's much more likely that this intern is feeling the pressure and just blanked out. I've been there myself. How much software development did you learn by the end of your first year of college, almost nothing. They're still at "this is a database", "this is a bit" levels.

My suggestion is to section off a bit of code that the intern can do by themselves, which can be validated and unit tested, and get him to build it independently. Answer his questions, but make sure they have to think through the work themselves. You'll get much better..

Comment: ... training effectiveness that way.

Further, I'd point out that by hiring someone with literally only a single year of university under their belt, you're effectively asking for someone with literally less than junior intern experience, since those typically have at least the degree. That's what you got. 

If the intern really has an issue with math, Khan academy has excellent math courses that they can take quickly on their own time to pave over anything they've missed in High School.

Answer (score 59):

Yes, you were a bit harsh on him, but I can certainly understand the frustrations.  The way you keep calm is to first understand what you're dealing with.

The lack of math skills is a problem that is at least 10 years old.  I remember having arguments with a few people over the years who argued that math was no longer a requirement of programming.  We're seeing the results of that now, and not just with your intern.  The schools are failing IT students all over the world.    When I was in college, the major was called "Math and Computer Science".  Math came first both in the title and focus.  This is not the case today, the proof is the existence of this intern.

Start with the smallest tasks and build from there.  It's obvious that whatever school he attended failed him miserably.  The lack of "getting it" is likely just a reaction to being overwhelmed.

Then, I would do a proper assessment of his skills, and have him do independent study on his own time.  This will achieve two things: 1)Free up your time. 2)Demonstrate how dedicated he is.  If he carries through with the independent study, you know he's dedicated, if not, you can cut him loose with a clean conscience.

Don't insult him again, but don't let him off the hook either.  Make it clear that he is lacking in areas that will prevent him from every being successful if he doesn't knuckle down.

Let him learn online from Kahn Academy, or youtube videos, again, on his own time.  Give him the opportunity to sink or swim on his own merits, and take a step back and breathe a bit.  Don't trash your own career over someone who's out of his depth.

Comment: Is it legal to require the intern to do independently study on his own time?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about math education has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51188/discussion-on-answer-by-richard-u-how-to-deal-with-an-interns-lack-of-basic-ski).

Comment: @TannerSwett What do you mean by *require*? He's not *required* to study at all, but he may need to in order to be competent at the tasks set before him. Actions have consequences. He can choose not to study, but if he doesn't learn the skills somehow, he won't keep the job. If someone is behind in the knowledge required to do the work required of them, they should *want* to learn the material necessary to catch up. If they need extra time, they should consider using their own time if they care about the job.

Comment: Paragraph 2 is the story people want to tell and hear, but people study CS in college or (less often) in high school. Multiplying fractions is something you learn in middle school at the latest (I'm pretty sure I was seeing exponentiation back in elementary school, but whatever). There's no way in hell any IT school has been failing students *so hard* and for *so long* that they somehow *un-learn* the elementary-school idea that multiplying a positive number by 0.95 or 19/20 makes it smaller. There's something wrong with this *kid* (like dishonesty), not his school.

Comment: @Mehrdad : I believe I learned this stuff in elementary school.  I also believe that different school districts are of different quality.  I also had the experience of having 8 different schools before my high school diploma.  Don't assume that everyone's school is like how you remember.

Comment: @TOOGAM: Are you saying you believe there are school districts where students can *systematically* go through *an entire K-12 education* and *still* not know basic fractions by they get their diplomas? I find that extremely hard to swallow, so if that's what you're saying, I'd like a link to back it up. If nothing else, as a last resort, I'd expect standardized testing to catch these sorts of issues.

Comment: @Mehrdad they can, and do, which is why I said that the schools are failing the students.  We've had this problem in my own extended family.  Long story short, the family actually had to pull a child from the school because they were going to promote her despite the fact that she was two grades behind in her skills.  This is not opinion, this is personal experience. The new school has brought her up to her own grade level.  So yes, TOOGAM is correct.

Comment: @RichardU: This isn't 2 grades behind though, this is more like 8 grades behind. I can certainly believe some district being 2-3 grades behind, but this?

Comment: @Mehrdad If a school is doing social promotions, this will sadly be the case.  I've seen the end results first hand.  Obviously, you went to a good school.  There is a shocking amount of schools that let you slide through.  But this is drifting off course.  If you want to go back to chat, I can discuss this with you more extensively and cite examples and statistics

Comment: @Mehrdad Regarding your earlier comment.  CS is not the only IT degrees they are giving these days.  Note, that from my day, it was MATH and computer science.  even the basic CS degree has dropped the math.  At my last job, I dealt with a guy who had an MIS degree.  Still an IT degree, but this guy couldn't count to 20 without taking off his shoes.  My answer is not what people want to hear, it's what I've observed personally.

Comment: @Mehrdad : The answer to your question is: yes.  I was fortunate enough to never experience such a horrendous education myself, but there is a preponderance of literature.  See also, the famously-titled article, "Little Johnny can't read" (referring to high school graduates).  I was shocked to hear of it at first (in the early '90s), but there is *so* much writing which testifies to such tremendous incompetence that I've come to believe what's been written.  So, yes, that is what I was saying.

Comment: "The schools are failing IT students all over the world." As someone who left college only a year or two ago I wholeheartedly agree with this. Though I will say making maths the key focus is also a mistake, there are many people who could be good programmers who would be scared off by maths because they don't like maths but still love programming.

Comment: @Pharap THat sort of does not matter. Scared of math? Sure, if you talk of brutal rare stuff. High level maths. But that level here is something in many countries you wold not even be allowed to a university with. Fractions are basic skills - you hit them all the time in life (calculating interest rates, rebates on something you buy).

Comment: @Pharap Largely agree, but higher math, even if you never actually use it in your code, teaches the problem solving skills necessary for programming.  IMO, it is a cornerstone of good programming.

Answer (score 45):

Let him go - better for you and better for him. You have not been too harsh. I personally profited a lot from the fact that (happened 2 times during my studies) people clearly expressed their dissatisfaction with my performance.

People who do not understand multiplication should not be let close to a programmable device.

As an alternative to letting him go: explain to him that he will get no recommendation from you - and if there is a grade explain to him that the grade may be bad and that it may be more reasonable to leave. Alternatively give him no tasks besides "self-study" and a seat without a computer - in that way at least you won't waste time time with him.

Comment: Agree. And OP should have tested him on technical skills during the interview.

Comment: This might benefit from an [edit] to explain how the OP should approach this, I suspect if they could snap their fingers and fire the intern they would have done that instead of asking this question.

Comment: It's an internship, wrap it up and move on, you don't have to bring him/her back.  I wouldn't be as harsh as @sascha but do cut him lose, tell him you don't feel he is ready yet and needs more study.  For future interns a little more rigor in the interviewing process may be necessary.

Comment: @BillLeeper To me, 'more study' would imply that progressing his degree will fix the problem.  It won't.  If the OP is giving the intern advice, it should be honest: he needs to learn basic math.  That's something you learn in primary school, not university.

Comment: @Alic Unfortunately, the hiring process wasn't on my hands. The decision to hire him was made by someone up on the chain.

Comment: Some folks just aren't very good. Odd but true.

Comment: After thinking about it , actually it is better to make him leave on his own - for his own sake; if he is asked in future interviews about this internship, he can tell that it was his choice to leave and nobody from the the current company needs to comment on his performance. Some sentence like: "I figured out that i lacked important theoretical knowledge to make the internship work" is much better than a internship description like: "learned 5th grade math"

Comment: @sapi I meant that as possibly a nice way to let him down.  You could tell him/her they have no future in IT and to give it up, which might be the truth, but that's up to you as to how brutally honest you want to be.

Answer (score 32):

> I'm actively teaching him for at least two hours a day every single day for two months now, and while he is showing some advances, they are rather small.

That raises huge red flags for me. That's 2 hours a day you could be spending doing development, management and other things that make money for the business.

This person is obviously a huge liability.

Apologize for the harsh remarks and go to your boss and let them know you cannot work with this person anymore and you'd like them off the team. If your organization is structured such that you're making that sort of call - let him go.

Once he's let go - you need to re-evaluate where you spend your time at the organization because you lost (at least) a whole month of work on this person - that's a month of features not developed, bugs not fixed and costumers not getting shipped value. You need to structure your policies so that it never happens again.

Even at the most optimistic case after half a year of tutoring them 2 hours a day they become half-decent - they can still just leave the following day.

Comment: Spending 2 hours a day on an intern is no red flag in itself. When the intern will become your colleague it's an investment, one that might be justified by his potential. In the type of organisation where you get such high potentials, you get them by good conditions which attract many potential interns. You must have a good filter to pick out those good interns. And obviously, all that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @MSalters if you spend 2 hours a day for half a year grooming an intern and then they quit after a year - it's not a good investment of your time. It only pays off at scale (if you have a hundred interns and one person spends 2 hours a day training them that's obviously fine).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's a usual part of our internship program. We offer a better-than-average salary and heavy tutoring for the intern to grow.

Comment: @ThalesPereira that's very generous of you - but from a business point of view you can probably tell if an intern is going to perform well after a month - and if they don't - keeping them around is a waste of time and money for the company and a waste of job satisfaction and happiness for you and your team. It's also probably very frustrating for the intern.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's surely true! I was a bit lucky until now, I think, because this is the very first time I'm given an intern with such low skills. I'll be honest and say I wasn't prepared to it, so maybe I had to send him to HR a few months ago. I think I was a bit naive in hoping that he would improve given enough time.

Comment: I just want to leave a comment that when I first started as an intern, straight out of 12 grade, at a software development house, I had 2 developers near me at all times, 1 pair programming and the other in case the first one missed something/didnt knew something specific to the language, for 2 whole years. I've never been more thankful, so much so I still work for them today as a project manager while they own the business.

Answer (score 15):

Sir James Goldsmith used to say "Pay peanuts, get monkeys". Paying peanuts if fine if you are looking for monkeys but if you want more than monkeys, you are going to have to up the ante. Firms don't hire interns with the expectation that said interns are capable of any useful work. The intent of internships is to help the interns not necessarily the firm.

Your intern's lack of math skills was a surprise discovery to you and most likely, a very unwelcome surprise. That's why I am leery of self-taught programmers who started out at age 13 and didn't attend uni.

Anyone can call themselves a programmer and sadly enough, your intern is a pretty on-point instance of that fact.

Expect that your intern's reading comprehension skills are not stellar either given that his progress in learning anything is slow and painful.

Your expectation that your intern will perform as a full fledged member of the team is most likely not going to be met given your intern's general educational deficiencies. If you are looking for a full fledged programmer, you are better off seeking a junior programmer not an intern. Yes, the intern is costing you nothing except your time. Well, add up the time you're spending training him - which exactly matches the amount of time you're not performing any useful work as a senior/team lead for the firm - and you should realize that the intern's ineffectiveness and inefficiency is costing your firm a pretty penny in terms of opportunity cost of work that's not done because you are spending so much time training him.

Losing your temper won't get you anywhere. You're losing your temper because you're frustrated and you're frustrated because you're stymied. You need to do something about the source of your frustration including sending him packing back to school to work on his deficiencies on his own time not on yours. He may not be happier because he has to be back in school but you most probably will be happier not to have to deal with his deficiencies - at the end of the day, you get to define what happiness means to you. At this point, you're going crazy dealing with him and nobody's happy. Consider that you're getting to the point where you've sailed past your ability to help him and you're no longer helping him but torturing him. Putting him out of his misery by the same token gives you a break. Not least because your relationship with him is definitely bringing the worst out of you. On top of the other costs, that kid is going to cost you in terms of reputation if you are not careful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51489/discussion-on-answer-by-vietnhi-phuvan-how-to-deal-with-an-interns-lack-of-basi).

Answer (score 7):

I guess you shouldn't teach, but should provide an opportunity to learn.

Two hours per day of your time, for months, seems to me an excessive investment in an intern.

Instead, just supply the tools they need. Choose and define (specify) tasks, which should be more-or-less within their ability to complete. Be available to answer questions (but not for extensive tutoring: point him at a book instead). Provide QA and feedback, review and testing, of their semi-finished work.

I'm not sure what programming tasks (if any) you could assign, which don't require arithmetic, though. The last time I used/borrowed an intern (which didn't take them very long) I asked the intern to install a specific test environment for me (which I needed, to test some software I was developing).

Answer (score 5):

> I had several other interns before, and none showed such slow-paced advances.

If you've had several great interns at this very company, on this very team, then you should check with HR. Ask them if you are managing your expectations for this internship (maybe those great interns were flukes? It happens, though it doesn't sound likely in this case).

If not, you might want to ask them if he's eligible for a performance improvement program. On paper, it gives him a set amount of time to improve based on projects dictated by you. In practice it creates a paper trail so that you can let him go.

Since you did say harsh words, you should apologize, and be kind to him for the remainder of the internship. It's neither your fault nor his that he landed on your team. Try to make the best of it until moves on, and applaud his efforts where you can.

Those 2 hour training sessions though - those need to end. Make him continue his training exercises until he starts to get them right on his own.

Comment: The training sessions are usual for our internship programs. We want them to learn all they can while they are here. If we manage to get a good employee at the end, awesome! If he jumps boat and go find something else, well, that's a bummer, but it's a risk we accept. We care a lot for our devs - it's hard to find good ones!

Comment: Ah, from your question I assumed that the training was extra-curricular. My bad! I'm so glad your company takes such good care of your developers!

Comment: We try everything we can to help them grow! Skilled software developers are so rare in my country that sometimes is easier "to grow your own" than to recruit them from the market. It is really sad to recruit someone with a impressive CV just to find out that this person can barely program anything without lots of help.

Comment: It may also be worth checking why this intern was hired (if that information is available to you). If your company hired a string of competent interns and then this fellow, perhaps he has other talents that are not yet apparent to you.

Answer (score 5):

If you were rude to the intern, apologize. Do it for yourself, if not for the intern.

Then fire the intern. It's one thing to mentor, it's another to be a university instructor for someone who didn't pay much attention.

Comment: +1. Short and to the point. The apology is warranted. The firing, obviously, too. If he asks why - tell him you are not there to teach elementary school knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things you need to cover:
A) What is your boss's expectations of you in regards to educating this person? Is making it clear this person is not qualified an option? Does anyone realize how much time you're spending/wasting? Make sure this intern isn't a relative of someone.
B) Have a conversation with the intern. What is his expectations? Does he realize how far behind he is? He may understand more, but is very intimidated in these one on one training sessions. He really does need to consider his future in this profession because the training you're offering isn't going to always be made available to him.

You may be doing all parties of favor and suggesting a different line of work. I can't imagine this is a pleasant experience for the intern. The company is wasting resources that they may not be aware of. If you can't get out of it for whatever reason, make the best of it. Back off on your expectations. Slow down and do a lot of reviewing. You never know, things may just click. Stranger things have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Be a manager.

You have a resource, an asset, a person.  Be nice and apologize.  You want men that will jump on a grenade for you.

Your problem is the application of the intern's skills.

Find something that the intern can own, and empower them.  Have manual tests?  Have a build server that needs to be babied?  Have sample data?  Need user #1?  All of these things are valuable to an organization, without writing or designing software.

Does the intern know what your company does?  Do they know the product?  Do they use the product?  I've found that having a "product expert" close to the team can be very beneficial.

Bottom line, your job is to find a role for the intern.  Not everybody can be a rockstar, but the world still needs gaffers.

Comment: -1. Obviously he does no have an asset, but a liability.